# Remove recent items in the Xcode's CheckOut window

Tags: xcode, xcode7

is there a way to clean recent items in the checkout dialog box ("source control" -> "check out...") on Xcode 7 ?

[image]

Comment: did you manage to solve this problem? i am hitting a dead end with it too.

Comment: No, the entries are still there, even with Xcode 7.3...

Comment: I managed to solve it on my own actually. You can refer to my own question which I also answered myself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617471/clearing-history-list-of-repositories-in-xcode

Comment: Great!! It works!! Answer to my question that I'll check it as right...

Comment: Glad that it helped you. I was pulling my hair out over this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you will need to find `com.apple.dt.XCode.plist` located in your Library/Preferences directory.

Search for IDESourceControlRecentsFavoritesRepositoriesUserDefaultsKey and there should be a list of items under that key. Unwanted repositories can be deleted from it and it will be reflected the next time XCode is restarted.

Such a difficult task for something to trivial. But hey, at least it is possible to do this. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

That window lists both:

- Projects/Workspaces that Xcode is tracking (and thus maintaining derived data for, like build products)
- Repositories that Xcode is holding login credentials for

For the first one, look in the [Projects window](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-projects_organizer/AboutProjectsWindow/AboutProjectsWindow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010346-CH2-SW1). You can clear things out of there, at the cost of losing the derived data associated with them.

For the second, look in the [Accounts pane](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/add_repository.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013306-CH4-SW1) of Xcode Preferences.

Once you've deleted things from both places, they shouldn't show up in the Check Out window anymore. (If they do, I'd call that a bug... [and file it with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com).)