# Clearing history list of repositories in XCode

Tags: xcode, git, repository

I am currently using SourceTree and Git for as my versioning tools and I only have two active projects that I am working on with it.

However, when I go to XCode -> Source Control -> Check Out, I see a list of repositories which I have either deleted or do not belong to me (since quite a number of people sent me their projects for review). I have searched my entire machine to for these values but have yet to find them. Here is a screenshot of how my Check Out window looks like:

[image: none]

I have also double checked on my Preferences -> Account to make sure only the two which I want are there.

[image: none]

I just want to keep the bottom two and remove the rest. Is this feat possible at all? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of searching my entire machine for these values, thanks to one tip from this answer:

[How to remove remote git urls from xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099035/how-to-remove-remote-git-urls-from-xcode?lq=1)

With some ideas from the answer posted in that qustion, I managed to solve without deleting the whole file and losing all my data/preferences.

It seems that you will need to find `com.apple.dt.XCode.plist` located in your `Library/Preferences` directory.

Search for `IDESourceControlRecentsFavoritesRepositoriesUserDefaultsKey` and there should be a list of items under that key. Unwanted repositories can be deleted from it and it will be reflected the next time XCode is restarted.

Just thought I would leave this here for those who wants to keep their XCode preferences uncluttered.