# Xcode: How do I clean a corrupt repository list?

Tags: xcode8, multiple-repositories

I have a list of repository locales that are not in sync with the accounts.  In fact, I think it is corrupt.   I tried to reset it via the Accounts in Preferences.   But there's no effect.

[image]

[image]

---

Where is the list of repository locales stored in Xcode so I can remove or re-sync them with the accounts?

Note: I'm also working within a workspace.

Comment: Please take a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617471/clearing-history-list-of-repositories-in-xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617471/clearing-history-list-of-repositories-in-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a "-" button on the bottom of the repository list:

[image]

Comment: I know.   I removed some repositories from preferences/accounts.
But the source code/checkout list remains the same. There's a dis-connect between the two.